# Cloth engine in Marvelous Designer

Tags: simulation, physics

I tried to find some information about marvelous designer  cloth solver but did not found it.
Who know which method they use? Position based? Spring forces?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about documenting internal implementation details of a particular product.

Comment: I can't agree with you. For example Physx. We can find a lot of information about its algorithms.